# Why possible duplicate questions are visible to all once posted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

With the frequency of questions being asked about basic issues which could be a possible candidate of being duplicate.

**Why can't Stackoverflow limit the visibility of these questions?**

- To reviewers when the question is being asked by someone with `Reputation 1-10`. Let the moderators decide if it should be visible to all something like voting which is currently present for any question which is flagged.

Once the question in put for review, it gives new users to browse through the platform and understand or possibly find the solution. Also i'm not sure if this functionality is already somewhere available in a different way.

Comment: That is already happening in the Triage

Answer (score 7):

So if I understand you correctly you'd like ALL questions asked by new users to require manual moderator approval first? That would horribly backfire and never scale. We get a metric ton of questions, a substantial amount of which are by new users. We only have a couple elected moderators, and they don't cover all tech stacks so there'd be no way.

In addition to this, finding the correct duplicate is sometimes hard work.

If by "moderators" you mean tag experts, then that may be a little more feasible although that would also not scale whatsoever. There are just too many new questions for that to make any sense.

Comment: Moderator would be wrong, i mean users having review privilege. Also not all questions, just the once which stackoverflow can detect based on the logic behind the platform with some percentage say 80%

Comment: @Bijendra So now you're suggesting they implement an algorhitm to predict duplicates. That's a whole new can of worms.

Comment: yes, may be the request is too broad.